# Error with attribute selector after upgrading jQuery 1.11 to 1.12

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a script which uses a selector like like so `$('img[src*=#]')`, which worked fine in an older project using jQuery 1.11. I just tried using the script in a new project with jQuery 1.12 and it choked, saying,

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: img[src*=#]

I found the solution easy enough, I had to add two slashes in front of the hashtag, one wasn't enough, so `img[src*=\\#]` works. But I am just wondering why this was necessary. I am worried that I am doing weird things and maybe there is a more proper way to do it. The answer may just be, "nope, that's fine", but then there is still the question of what changed between jQuery versions.

Comment: Ah yes, that works too.

Comment: was it my suggestion (`img[src*='#']`) that I deleted because I thought wouldn't work?

Comment: Haha, yes. And in the jQuery documentation I see that their examples actually use quotes.